# firing event after the dom has loaded jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, bootstrap-typeahead, jquery-tokeninput

I have my initial jquery which works fine.

```
jQuery ->
  $(".question_tags").tokenfield typeahead:
    name: 'question_tags'
    valueKey: 'name'
    prefetch: '/admin/question_tags.json'
```

But the problem is when I'm adding new form fields after the dom has loaded.

In addition to the above, I tried to attach a new token field event to the click when it adds the additional fields but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
  $(".question_tags").tokenfield typeahead:
    name: 'question_tags'
    valueKey: 'name'
    prefetch: '/admin/question_tags.json'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
$("document").on ('click', 'form.add_fields', your-code);
```